# Does Flash Player 11 force apps written for flash below 10.2 to use HW Acceleration?

Tags: flash-builder, flash, flashdevelop

I've got a question for Flash Developers.
I would like to know if current Flash Player 11.x can force old apps/games (written for version below 10.2) to use Hardware Acceleration?

If you got any answer, please provide the reliable source.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HWA is a feature of Flash Player, not a method in a particular app. So, it'll work even in flash6-written swf, if you hardware supports this technology.